# Save popup window's data into database

Tags: javascript, php

I m trying to save popup windows data in to database.but its throw error when i m trying pass data in queryString.Its just write "error".I dont know why its not call the update_clientstatus.php

Javscript :

```
function SaveNotes()
{
var notecontent = $("#txtPopNotes").val();
lookup(notecontent, globalNoteId);

overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
return false;
}

 function lookup(inputstr, eleid) {
    var inputString =  inputstr;

    // var row = parseFloat(eleId.substring(eleId.indexOf('_') + 1))+1;
    var noteId = '#noteContent_' + eleid;
    var editLinkId = '#editlink_' + eleid;
    var saveLinkId = '#savelink_' + eleid;
    var cancelLinkId = '#cancellink_' + eleid;
    var txtBoxId = '#txt_' + eleid;
    // var eleId = ele.id;

    $.post("update_clientstatus.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+"", id: ""+eleid+"" }, function(data){
        if(data=="success") {

            alert("Status updated successfully");
            $('.popup').hide();
            var noteId = '#noteContent_' + globalNoteId;
            $(noteId).html(inputstr);
            $('.message').html('Status Updated successfully');
        }
        else
        {
            **document.write('error');**
        }
    });

} // lookup
```

PHP code(update_clientstatus.php)

```
 if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {

        $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
        $eleid = $_POST['id'];          
        $query = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE tblclientmaster SET status = '$queryString' WHERE id= '$eleid'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {

        $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
        $eleid = $_POST['id'];          
        $query = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE tblclientmaster SET status = '$queryString' WHERE id= '$eleid'");
        if ($query ) {
           echo "success";
        } else {
           echo "error";
        }
} else {
   echo "error";
}
```

Comment: I already did it.problem is it cant call the update_clientstatus.php

Comment: where is javascript file is located and where is php file is located?

Comment: zzlalani is right. If you were getting the document.write("error") firing, it's because the AJAX request was made, completed, and called the callback function you gave it. Perhaps it's not resolving to the right URL. Are you inspecting the http request in your browser's developer tools? Is it going to the right place?

Comment: both files are in one folder

Comment: in your javascript can you do `console.log(data)` before the if condition.. ?

Comment: and I add this line.But now problem with query.

Comment: what is the problem with query?

Comment: Now its going in debugging mode?Now I dont know whats this

Comment: what is `debugging mode`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41308/discussion-between-zzlalani-and-aanshi)